# finally in exception handling

Tags: java, exception, finally

What exactly does a `finally` block in exception handling perform?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It holds code that should always be executed, regardless of whether an exception occurs.

For example, if you have opened a file, you should close it in the `finally` block to ensure that it will always be closed; if you closed it in the `try` block, an earlier exception would cause execution to jump straight to the `catch` block and skip closing the file.

See the [Java tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

The finally block always executes, regardless of whether or not the exception was thrown. The classic use example I can think of is closing files.

```
FileOutputStream stream = null;
try{
    // do stuff with the stream here
} catch (IOException ex){
    // handle exception
} finally{
    // always close the stream
    if(stream != null){
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I just realized that this won't actually work because stream.close() itself throws an exception! Yet another reason why I dislike Java exceptions. The example should still show the general use pattern however, so I'll leave it up.

Comment: A better way of arranging the code is: `acquire(); try { use(); } finally { release(); }`.

Answer (score 3):

It executes no matter if you get into the `catch` block or not, meaning that is a great place for disposing of objects and doing other cleanups.

Answer (score 2):

I use it a lot for cleaning up open resources when there are multiple return statements in a block of code, making the code a lot cleaner as you don't need to clone the same 'close resource' code before every return statement. It's guaranteed that the code will call the finally section, even if you do a return within the try section. It also helps with code safety in this instance, since the programmer could easily leave it out by accident.

Answer (score 0):

If you return a value in your `try` or `catch` block as well as in the `finally` block, keep in mind that the `finally` block's return value is what you'll end up with (the last block executed).  That means if you `try` some code that does NOT throw an `Exception` and is supposed to return a value, but your `finally` block is also supposed to return a value, the `finally` block's value is what will actually be returned.  [This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run) talks about that very point.  I don't believe returning a value inside a `try` or `catch` is usually necessary or the best idea.  Also note that `System.exit(0)` kills the JVM and thus halts execution before anything else runs, which might render your `finally` block unexecuted.

Answer (score 0):

finally block is mainly used to perform close statement for example **con.close** that is to close connection from database....try block is always followed by either catch block or finally (or both also)...If you once entered in the try  block then your finally block will be definately execute except system error,exception in finally block....**Main key point of finally block** is that it always be executed even the exception is handled or not..

Answer (score 0):

finally keyword is used just to make sure that code present in finally block must execute in all circumstances irrespective of exception occurances.

for eg:

```
 try{
     }
     catch(Exception e){
     }
      finally{
             System.out.print("finally executed");
            }
```

Note: In above case finally will always execute.

Answer (score 0):

Though there are many answers have already given that `finally` block is required to execute some piece of code in all the conditions whether there is some interruption due to exception, or some bad code, or you return the program control flow from `try` block, Here I'm adding an example to explain the need of `finally` block;

Let's suppose [you have borrowed a pen](https://medium.com/@amitgupta.gwl/what-is-exception-handling-752435bc6b8a) from your friend. You use it and then return ( I consider you a gentleman). Now whatever happens, you have to return the pen. You can handle various situations and you put most unavoidable condition in `finally` block.

```
//Borrow the pen
try{
  //Use the pen
}catch(StolenPen how){
  //Buy new pen
}catch(InkFinished how){
  //Refill the pen
}catch(SomethingWrong how){
  //Buy new pen
}finally{
  //Return new pen
}
```