# Is this a dangerous locking pattern?

Tags: c#, locking, yield-return

I have an enumerator written in C#, which looks something like this:

```
try
{
    ReadWriteLock.EnterReadLock();
    yield return foo;
    yield return bar;
    yield return bash;
}
finally
{
    if (ReadWriteLock.IsReadLockHeld)
        ReadWriteLock.ExitReadLock();
}
```

I believe this may be a dangerous locking pattern, as the ReadWriteLock will only be released if the enumeration is complete, otherwise the lock is left hanging and is never released, am I correct? If so, what's the best way to combat this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, the `finally` block will always be executed, pretty much unless somebody pulls the plug from the computer ([well and a *few* other exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run)).

```
public static IEnumerable<int> GetNumbers() {
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        yield return 1;
        yield return 2;
        yield return 3;
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Finish");
    }
}
```

...

```
foreach(int i in GetNumbers()) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
    if(i == 2) break;
}
```

The output of the above will be

> Start
> 1
> 2
> Finish

Note that in C# you write `yield return`, not just `yield`. But I guess that was just a typo.

Comment: What if somebody does not use foreach but makes a single call to MoveNext() and Current?

Comment: @David, @Martin: This answer is misleading and codymanix is correct. A simple one-liner -- `GetNumbers().GetEnumerator().MoveNext();` -- will display "Start" and then nothing else (and if you were using locking in your example then your lock would never be released).

Comment: @codymanix, @LukeH: this is true. i didn't think of that scenario.
@Martin: i'd opt to delete this answer as it is misleading, as others have pointed out, altho i can't, since this is accepted. if you untick the accept-box, i'll delete this post, so as to not mislead anybody else

Comment: I have unaccepted the answer as you asked. Personally I would just update the answer to reflect this issue. In reality the way I am actually using this enumerator is as a generator that never finishes, so I have already fixed this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I think [David's answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956733/is-this-a-dangerous-locking-pattern/2956783#2956783) the question you intended to ask (about the enumeration aspect), but two additional points to consider:

1. What would happen if `ReadWriteLock.EnterReadLock` threw an exception?
2. What would happen if `ReadWriteLock.ExitReadLock` threw an exception?

In #1, you'll call `ReadWriteLock.ExitReadLock` inappropriately. In #2, you may hide an existing exception that's been thrown (since `finally` clauses happen either because the mainline processing reached the end of the `try` block *or* because an exception was thrown; in the latter case, you probably don't want to obscure the exception). Perhaps both of those things are unlikely in this specific case, but you asked about the *pattern*, and as a pattern it has those issues.

Comment: Hmm, those are good points. number 1 just caught me out elsewhere and I shall update my sample above to reflect how I fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

Finally will be executed in any way, but for locking in may not be safe. Compare following methods:

```
class Program
{
    static IEnumerable<int> meth1()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter");
            yield return 1;
            yield return 2;
            yield return 3;
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exit");
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> meth2()
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter");
            return new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exit");
        }
    }

    static public void Main()
    {
        foreach (int i in meth1())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (int i in meth2())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In");
        }   
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Enter
In
In
In
Exit

Enter
Exit
In
In
In
```

If your processing takes much time (per iteration) it is more reasonable to fill collection first, then process, but not yield.