# Why use finally

Tags: java, try-catch-finally

I never properly understood the use of the finally statement. Can anyone tell me what the difference is between:

```
try {
    a;
    block;
    off;
    statements;
} catch (Exception e) {
    handle;
    exception;
    e;
} finally {
    do;
    some;
    cleanup;
}
```

on the one hand and:

```
try {
    a;
    block;
    off;
    statements;
} catch (Exception e) {
    handle;
    exception;
    e;
}
do;
some;
cleanup;
```

On the other

Answer (score 45, accepted):

They differ if

- the `try`-block completes by throwing a `java.lang.Throwable` that is not a `java.lang.Exception`, for instance because it is a `java.lang.Error` such as `AssertionError` or `OutOfMemoryError`.
- the try-block completes abruptly using a control flow statement such a `continue`, `break` or `return`
- the catch-block completes abruptly (by throwing any throwable, or using a control flow statement)

More generally, the java language guarantees that a finally block is executed before the try-statement completes. (Note that if the try-statement does not complete, there is no guarantee about the finally. A statement might not complete for a variety of reasons, including hardware shutdown, OS shutdown, VM shutdown (for instance due to `System.exit`), the thread waiting (`Thread.suspend()`, `synchronized`, `Object.wait()`, `Thread.sleep()`) or being otherwise busy (endless loops, ,,,).

So, a `finally` block is a better place for clean-up actions than the end of the method body, but in itself, still can not guarantee cleanup exeuction.

Answer (score 31):

`finally` block executes always.

`finally` block is used for cleanup, like to free resources used within `try`/`catch`, close db connections, close sockets, etc.. even when an unhandled exception occurs within your `try`/`catch` block.

The only time the `finally` block doesn't execute is when`system.exit()` is called in `try`/`catch` or some error occurs instead of an exception.

The error in the description above means when Java application exit with conditions like Out Of Memory error. I see some downvotes :( for this reason it seems.

Comment: Correction: a finally block _is_ executed when a java.lang.Error is thrown. It might not execute successfully, but it does execute. Also, there are additional conditions that may thwart the execution of a finally block, see my answer for an incomplete list.

Comment: Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute even though the application as a whole continues.  - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 24):

The main difference is that the `catch` section might itself throw an exception, break out of a surrounding block, or return from the current method. In that case `do; some; cleanup;` is not executed.

With a `finally` block, it is *guaranteed* that that code will be executed.

Comment: Is finally guaranteed to be executed?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run

Comment: Yes, not in case of System.exit(), that is true. Or, you know, a JVM crash.

Comment: ... or a deadlock, or ... - the real rule is: A finally-block is guaranteed to have executed when/if the try-(catch)-finally statement completes.

Answer (score 13):

It's basically a bad idea to catch all exceptions - so you need to consider what will happen if an uncaught exception propagates up out of your try/catch or try/catch/finally block. Finally blocks allow you to clean up on the way out.

Also:

- The catch block might throw an exception
- You may want to return from the try block

In short, if you want some code to be executed when you leave the try/catch block *however* you're leaving it (aside from the process being terminated very hard), finally is your friend.

Answer (score 10):

In proper coding style you don't want to do a catch all as below.

```
try{
  [some task] 
}
catch
{
}
```

What you would want to do is catch specific known errors.

```
try{
  [some task] 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   if([known execption])
     [ignore]
   else
     throw(ex);
}
[Cleanup]
```

In this case   your cleanup code will not be run in the case of an error being thrown again.  So we add in the finally which will get run even if a new error is thrown.

```
try{
  [some task] 
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   if([known execption])
     [ignore]
   else
     throw(ex);
}
finally
{
   [Cleanup]
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The "finally" block will always execute.

In your second example, the cleanup would not occur if the catch block rethrows the exception, or if an uncaught exception occurred in the try block.

Comment: There are numerous conditions where the finally is not executed (c.f. my answer), but you are correct that throwing exceptions (or using control flow statements) are not among them.

Answer (score 3):

From [this](http://www.geekinterview.com/talk/7841-purpose-of-finally-block.html) forum on GeekInterview:

> The finally block always executes when the try block exits. This ensures that the finally block is executed even if an unexpected exception occurs. But finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break. Putting cleanup code in a finally block is always a good practice, even when no exceptions are anticipated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply one line of explanation:

regardless whether you caught an exception or not, codes in the `finally` block will get executed.

the diff between the two pieces you gave here is: the codes in the piece without using `finally` will never get executed.

to properly understand `finally`, all you need to know is that `finally` = guarantee!

you can use it to clean up, to help w/ user friendliness or to retry something

Comment: this is really old, but it is not a guarantee that the finally will execute. Quick example is System.exit(0); There are many more examples which I will not list and I believe have been listed in other answers.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the finally block always gets executed even if you have a return statement in the try clause. The only time it doesn't get executed is when you have System.exit(0).

Comment: there are numerous other conditions where the finally is not executed, c.f. my answer (which doesn't claim to give all of them ...)