# Is there any way to avoid the finally clause to get executed?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a finally block always run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run)

I learned that the finally clause of a try catch statement, executes always. But some guy said to me that it is possible to avoid executing it(removing it is not an option).

-Does someone how is that possible?

-Also i am curious in knowing why would someone want to avoid to execute it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run

Comment: Also see this post-> [how-to-use-finally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354823/how-to-use-finally)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kill it with an uncaught exception within the `finally` block, or kill the overall JVM (which kills the thread, among other things).

There is no good reason to stop the execution of a `finally` block except poor design. If it's not supposed to run every time, then don't put it in a `finally` block.

---

Using the below test code, I run two different scenarios to see what happens when killing the `Thread`:

1. Start the `Thread` and `sleep` the main thread for 2 seconds. Within the `Thread`, pretty much immediately enter the `finally` block and then sleep for 5 seconds. Once the main thread is finished waiting, kill the `Thread` using `stop`.
2. Start the `Thread` and sleep 2 seconds. Within the `Thread`, sleep 5 seconds before entering the `finally` block and then sleep some more within the `finally` to give it a chance to be killed.

In the first case, the result is that the `finally` block stops executing.
In the second case, the result is that the `finally` block executes completely, and on the `Thread` that was `stop`ped no less.

Output (note the name of the current thread added for all output):

```
thread-starting [main]
trying [Thread-0]
catching [Thread-0]
finally-sleeping [Thread-0]
thread-stopped [main]
 [main]
thread-starting [main]
trying-sleeping [Thread-1]
thread-stopped [main]
finally-sleeping [Thread-1]
finally-done [Thread-1]
```

Code:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        testThread(new TestRunnable());
        println("");
        testThread(new TestRunnable2());
    }

    private static void testThread(Runnable runnable)
    {
        Thread testFinally = new Thread(runnable);

        println("thread-starting");

        testFinally.start();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            println("main-interrupted...");
        }

        testFinally.stop();

        println("thread-stopped");
    }

    private static class TestRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                println("trying");
                throw new IllegalStateException("catching");
            }
            catch (RuntimeException e)
            {
                println(e.getMessage());
            }
            finally
            {
                println("finally-sleeping");

                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    println("finally-interrupted");
                }

                println("finally-done");
            }
        }
    }

    private static class TestRunnable2 implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                println("trying-sleeping");

                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                println("trying-interrupted");
            }
            finally
            {
                println("finally-sleeping");
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    println("finally-interrupted");
                }
                println("finally-done");
            }
        }
    }

    private static void println(String line)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s [%s]%n", line, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        System.out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree -- System.exit(...) will prevent the finally from executing.

Comment: You can't kill the Thread in a way which avoid the finally block without killing the JVM.  e.g. Thread.stop() still calls finally blocks.

Comment: @Peter I meant to add "by throwing an uncaught exception within the `finally` block" but it for some reason blanked when I started typing. Will edit, which actually has less to do with the `Thread` as my brain is thinking at the moment.

Comment: Evil thought - You can make the JVM run out of memory in the `try` block and that will make `finally` not execute :P

Comment: @Peter are you sure about that? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run/464102#464102

Comment: @matt I think this might be a long held myth. I heard that a long time ago and simply agreed with it (`Thread.stop()` does not prevent `finally` executing). I'm going to make a small example to test that theory.

Comment: @matt b, Perhaps there is a way of "killing" a thread I wasn't aware of which doesn't kill the JVM, but you cannot stop() a thread without calling the finally block.

Comment: Would love to see some example code for this theory; since the quote comes from a Sun tutorial it is pretty official-sounding. Note though they might be referring to another way of killing or interrupting the thread than `Thread.stop()`

Comment: @matt I hadn't noticed Peter's concise example below, but I added my own with a small twist as well (killing the `Thread` while in the `finally` block).

Answer (score 4):

-Does someone how is that possible?

```
System.exit(0);
```

-Also i am curious in knowing why would someone want to avoid to execute it?

```
To answer questions like these and appear smart. ;)
```

---

BTW, Thread.stop() doesn't prevent `finally` being called.

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Thread start");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("Thread end");
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
        } catch (Error e) {
            System.out.println("Thread threw an error " + e);
            throw e;
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Thread finally");
        }
    }
};
t.start();
t.join(100);
t.stop();
```

prints

```
Thread start
Thread threw an error java.lang.ThreadDeath
Thread finally
```

Comment: Hehe... This is a good answer specially the second part :)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way of avoiding it, unless something external happens such as the Java Virtual Machine shutting down.

As a general rule you should always assume that a finally block will run. The whole point of it is to ensure that it runs regardless of what happens in the try block - there should be no reason to avoid it!

Answer (score 0):

To your first question i think the only way that comes to my mind is by creating an infinite loop or something.(But it makes no sense at all)

```
try{
    while(true);
}
catch(Exception e) {
}
finally {
//..
}
```

To your second question, i don't really know why would someone want to do something like that

See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6228601/edit

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a good reason that you would want to avoid a finally block.  If you really don't want to use this feature, then just don't implement a finally block (at your own risk however).

Killing the JVM would do it, but that's not really an acceptible solution for any production code.

Why is removing a finally block not an option?