# When should I use the finally-block in Java's try-catch-finally

Tags: java, exception

When should I use code snippet A instead of snippet B (i.e. what are the benefits of using snippet A)?:

**Snippet A:**

```
try {
    // codeblock A
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // codeblock B
}
finally {
    //codeblock C
}
```

**Snippet B:**

```
try {
    // codeblock A
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // codeblock B
}

//codeblock C
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354823/how-to-use-finally

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a finally block if you have code that must execute regardless of whether or not an exception is thrown.

Cleaning up scarce resources like database connections are a good example.

Comment: It's also good practice because it explicitly states what is going on, e.g. regardless of execution we must free resource x, etc.

Comment: Note, in Java 7 you can use a try-with-resources statement to close certain resources, so you wouldn't need a `finally` in this case.

Comment: @duffymo But wouldn't `codeblock C` in _snippet B_ also take care of this?

Comment: Not guaranteed if someone puts a return in the catch block.

Answer (score 3):

An obvious case is when you re-raise or throw another exception in your `catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

It's useful if you need to do some cleanup, e.g. close a database connection. Because "finally" is executed always, you don't need to do the bug-prone copy-paste of the same code in the end of the "try" and in also in one or more "catch" blocks.

Answer (score 1):

You must almost always use the snippet with finally block when you have resources that needs clean up in both successful or error scenarios. A typical example is the jdbc connection object which should always be closed (clean up) in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine to have a `return` statement inside the `catch` block: the **C** block will not be executed in snippet **B**, but in snippet **A** it will, before returning.