# Call return statement or System.exit on try or catch block

Tags: java

I got the following question asked in interview :

> What will happen if one calls a return statement or System.exit on try
>   or catch block ?  Will finally block execute?

Does the finally block always get executed?

**EDIT:**
After trying the above in java:

1. `finally` block executes if I put return statement in try block or catch block but
2. `finally` block doesn't run if I call System.exit form try or catch.

I don't get the reason  behind though.

Comment: Check above edit now

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html, finally does not run if JVM exits in a `try` or `catch` block.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354823/how-to-use-finally

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What will happen if one calls a return statement or System.exit on try 
>   or catch block ?
>
> Will finally block execute?

In the case of a `return`, Yes.  If you want the gory details, they are specified in [JLS section 14.20.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2).

(Note that in the JLS terminology, a `return` counts as an *abrupt termination*.  But that doesn't matter, because when you analyse the spec carefully, you will see that the `finally` gets executed for both *normal* and *abrupt* terminations.)

In the case of a `System.exit()`, No.  The call to the `exit` method never returns, and it doesn't throw an exception either. Therefore the "enclosing" `finally` clauses for the thread never get executed.

(In JLS parlance, the `exit()` call doesn't "terminate" at all.  It conceptually the same as a method going into an infinite loop that (magically) doesn't use any CPU time.  All of the activity associated with JVM shutdown happens on other threads.)

Answer (score 3):

According to [the tutorials from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html):

> Note: If the JVM exits while the try or catch code is being executed, then
>       the finally block may not execute. Likewise, if the thread executing the try
>       or catch code is interrupted or killed, the finally block may not execute
>       even though the application as a whole continues.

This statement seems to imply that:

- The `finally` block **will not** execute if `System.exit(0)` is called (**since the Java VM exits when that statement is called**)
- it **will** execute when a `return` statement is called (**since the Java VM does not exit when that statement is called**).

You can confirm this with some code I quickly wrote up:

```
public class TryExample {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try {
            int[] i = {1, 2, 3};
            int x = i[3];//Change to 2 to see "return" result
            return;
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            System.out.println("caught");
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            System.out.println("finally");
        }
    }
}
```

Here, when `return` is called in the `try` block, "finally" is still output to terminal, but when `System.exit(0)` is called in the `catch` block, it is not.

Comment: @StephenC Edited to refer to link merely as "the tutorials" rather than "official documentation"

Answer (score 2):

No it wont, when the try-catch does not complete normally then finally block wont get executed.

Here is the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) or it and states:

```
If execution of the try block completes normally, then the finally block is executed
```

same for **catch block**

```
 If the catch block completes normally, then the finally block is executed.
```

Since you are calling `System.exit` which terminate the program within the `try block` then try-catch does not complete normally thus `finally block` wont get executed.

For the `return statement` try-catch does complete normally because you are not blocking the `try block`(such as an infinite loop, sleeping the thread, terminating the program, etc.) thus `finally block` is executed after you return from the method.