# Bypass a Java error

Tags: java, error-handling

Is there a way that I can bypass an error message in Java ?
What if I get an error, but there is no viable way to change my program ? What if I suspect that I might get an error from a block of code, but I don't know when or if it will happen ? There's been a lot of times where I had to let something be in my code, but produced an error. For example, converting a string into a float with parseFloat().

Anyway to do this ?

Comment: As the answers suggest _Exception handling work_ .  But nothing can be done when  _there is no viable way to change my program ?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes** you can handle runtime errors in Java.

**Exception Handling**

There are two ways to handle Exceptions.

1. **Throw out and ignore -**

When an Exception occur inside a code of program simply throw it out and ignore that an exception occur(i.e.declare the methods as `throws Exception`).

Example:

```
void method()throws IOException{  

 }
```

2. **Catch and handle -**

If a code snippet is generating an `Exception` place it inside a `try` block. Then mention the way to handle the `Exception` inside the `catch` block.

Example for catch and handle:

```
try{
  double a= parseDouble("12.4a");
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
  System.out.println("cannot format");
}
```

Here try to convert `12.4a` to `double` and store in `a`. Since `12.4a` contains character `a` `NumberFormatException` will occur. you can handle it. In above code I just print a text. But you get `printStackTrace`:

```
e.printStackTrace;
```

You can add [`finally`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354823/how-to-use-finally) after catch block. read [Orcale doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need a `try...catch` statement.

```
try {
    // parse your float here
} catch (NumberFormatException ex) { // parsing a float might throw a NumberFormatException
    // code in here will be executed if a NumberFormatException occurs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, of course there is a way to do this, it is called *Exception Handling*.

Begin by reading about the *`Exception`* class, and the `try` `catch` and `finally` keywords.

Here is a starting point: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_exceptions.htm

Comment: Hey Mike, I just noticed that I never gave you an upvote for helping me when I was a complete newbie, and so I apologise about that :) Here you go!