# While loop inside try block

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to put a while loop inside a try /catch block. To my curiosity finally of that try catch is not executed when the while loop exits. Can some explain what  is happening actually?
I tried to google, but cnould not find any details.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: According to the JLS what you describe cannot happen.  Please show us the code that demonstrates this behaviour.  (My guess is that you are misinterpreting something ...)

Comment: @StephenC yes it can, see my answer.

Comment: Yea ... well apart from that, or crashing the JVM.  (And I'm sure that is not what the OP is actually talking about!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume your code looks like this:

```
try
{
    while (...)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
catch (FooException ex)
{
    // This only executes if a FooException is thrown.
}
finally
{
    // This executes whether or not there is an exception.
}
```

The catch block is only executed if there is an exception. The finally block **usually** executes whether or not an exception was thrown. So you will probably find that your finally block is actually being executed. You can prove this to yourself by placing a line there that causes some output to the console.

However there are situations in which the finally block doesn't run. See here for more details:

- [Does a finally block always run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464098/does-a-finally-block-always-run)

Comment: It sounds like he is referring to a `finally` block, no?

Comment: @cheeken: OK, yeah I see what you mean. Question is hard to understand. He should post his code.

Comment: This is what i have given as statement. What will happen after the while loop finished its execution?

Comment: @Tinkerbel - the `finally` block will be executed in that case.

Answer (score 1):

It can happen only if your program exits either by using `System.exit()` or if an `Error` or `Throwable` were thrown (vs. `Exception` that will be caught).

Try the following:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {         
        try{
            System.out.println("START!");
            int i=0;
            while(true){
                i++;
                if(i > 10){
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        finally{
            System.out.println("this will not be printed!");
        }
    }
```